# What is the equivalent of Get-Mailbox (powershell) in Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I am looking for a method to get the list of all mailboxes through graph api.

List users returns all the users no matter they have mailbox enabled or not, is there any graph api call that can get me the list of all the mailboxes in office 365 using graph API? or any properties that can indicate a user have mailbox enabled?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Please use list place API. refer to the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Also, you can search individual mailbox details using Get place API.

(I know it's late. But this may help somebody else also.)

Comment: This does not answer the question, though. The list places API lists room and roomList objects, not user mailboxes.